# canonical synonym for "parameter respect" in engineering

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, computing

I thought about it couple of days ago and have uneasy feeling that my usage is not canonical, i.e. not common. Googling didn't really help.

I am looking for common way to say something like "System X respects parameter Y". Real-world example: "Domain name server respects TTL (time-to-live) parameter of the domain"

Another way to say it that I have seen on Internet, is to use "honor" instead of "respect". Googling yields same number of entries for DNS respect and honor.

Is there more canonical way to say it?

In other words, how do people in engineering say that system does what it says it will in respect to certain parameter?

Comment: _Follows_ perhaps.

Comment: Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must [include information on how it will be used](//english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) in order to be answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on EngineeringSE. Such subject-specific usages are too esoteric to be appropriate on a general language site, and dedicated sites such as MathsSE have their own terminology sections. / I've come across the string 'remains/is loyal to' for a similar situation in linguistics.

Comment: i wasn't sure if that is off-topic. When people go to specialized sites and ask "how do I say X", they often being send to english@SE :)

Comment: I would open a new question, tag it phrase request, and write down exactly what you're trying to say.

Comment: I would propose: *accurately reflects*.

Answer (score 1):

*Respect* should work fine, and some other synonyms are: *comply with, follow, adhere to, conform to, act in accordance with*.

They all share the sense "(of an article) meet specified standards." for this context. -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comply)